# Mistral AI Suddenly Running Much Slower

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model

Hello I am trying to prompt a version of Mistral AI that I have stored locally on my computer. During my first test, I seemed to get about a 100 token response in 10 seconds with 4bit quantization, so seemingly around 600 tokens/min. Today I have created a new script to load it from my local folder, but it seems to be running much much slower, even with 4bit quantization. I'm having to wait 2-3 minutes for barely 10 tokens. Below is the code I use to load in the LLM and quantize it:

```
quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_4bit=True, 
                                         llm_int8_enable_fp32_cpu_offload=True,
                                         bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
                                         bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16)

loaded_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained('./mistral_model_7B_8bit_Q/', quantization_config=quantization_config)

model_id = "mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
pipeline = pipeline(
        "text-generation",
        model=loaded_model,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        use_cache=True,
        device_map="auto",
        max_length=500,
        do_sample=True,
        top_k=5,
        num_return_sequences=1,
        eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
        pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
)

llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipeline)
```

I believe this correctly loads in the quantized model. With a 7B parameter model at 4 bit quantization, I'm expecting to get a faster turn around. My GPU is an RTX 3080 Ti.